# Probability question for arrangement

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, contest-math

Eight boys and seven girls went to the movies and sat in the same row of 15 seats. Assuming
that all the 15! permutations of their seating arrangements are equally likely, compute the
expected number of pairs of neighbors of different genders.

I believe the answer to the above question is 7.67. Could someone confirm or give hints to solve?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You need to add your efforts. Otherwise, your question will be closed because this is not a place for others to do their homework. Hint: You can use a set of indicators for all the pairs to compute the expectation.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that an ordered pair of kids is a pair of $1$ boy and $1$ girl is $\frac{8\cdot7 + 7\cdot8}{15\cdot14} = \frac8{15}$

Now note that the number of positions where such a pair could be seated = $14$ (because they could be at $1,2$ or $2,3$ or ... or $14,15$). Hence, each of the $14$ adjacent pairs of seats has a probability of $\frac8{15}$ of having a mixed pair on average.

By [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/#:%7E:text=Linearity%20of%20expectation%20is%20the,of%20whether%20they%20are%20independent.), the
expected number of mixed adjacent pairs = $14 \cdot \frac8{15} = \frac{\textbf{212}}{\textbf{15}}$

Comment: This question does not meet the [standards for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.